# How do I use scipy.ndimage.interpolate to randomly rotate a numpy array in 3d?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I made a square in 3 dimensions that is essentially a 3d version of this:

```
        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

You can see a *3x3* square of ones. In 3d, in a plot, it gives this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

square = np.ones((8, 8, 8)) 
x, y, z = np.where(square ==1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, alpha=.8, s=100, ec='k', color='#2FAA75')
ax.set_xlim(-5, 10), ax.set_ylim(-5, 10), ax.set_zlim(-5, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I want is this straight square to rotate of various angles, **not only 90 degrees**.

I know that [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html) can do that. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it. **Expected results:** imagine the cube being rotated 45 degrees with respects to the `x` and `z` axes (for example).

Comment: %matplotlib notebook
 add this line at the top of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the cube being rotated 45 degrees with respects to the x and z axes

```
# ...
coords = np.where(square == 1)
coords = np.transpose(coords)          # get coordinates into a proper shape

rot = Rotation.from_euler('xz', [45, 45], degrees=True)  # create a rotation
coords = rot.apply(coords)             # apply the rotation
coords = np.transpose(coords)          # get coordinates back to the matplotlib shape

# ...

ax.scatter(*coords, alpha=.8, s=100, ec='k', color='#2FAA75')
```

> randomly rotate a numpy array in 3d?

Replace the rotation with

```
rot = Rotation.random()
```